# Rails - how to enforce one method call per method, like controllers do with `render`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So in Rails, you get an error if you try to call `render` multiple times within a controller action.

I have another Ruby class that I'm writing, and I'd like to try to do something similar (make sure that my own `respond_with` method is only called once.

So for example, this would be fine:

```
def my_method
  if (my_value == true)
    ...
    respond_with(:a, :b, :c)
  else
    ...
    respond_with(:x, :y, :z)
  end
end
```

But this would raise an error if `my_value == 4`

```
def my_method
  if (my_value >= 4)
    ...
    respond_with(:a, :b, :c)
  end

  if (my_value <= 4)
    ...
    respond_with(:d, :e, :f)
  else
    ...
    respond_with(:x, :y, :z)
  end
end
```

Any thoughts on how to best accomplish that?

Comment: In your second example the respond_with function will only be called once...

Comment: Oops, you're correct.  Sorry, I was just constructing a simplified example on the fly.  It has now been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

```
class MyBaseClass
  def respond_with(arguments)
    if @rendered
      raise DoubleRenderError #or whatever
    end
    @rendered = true
    #whatever the respond_with function should do
  end
end
```

Comment: I'll try that out, but my thought is that doing that wouldn't work.  For example, if you have two different methods, you need to make sure that respond_with is only called once per unique method, not just once ever, right?

Comment: As long as all the methods are instance methods called on the same class instance then this will work.

Comment: Let's call the object that has respond_with "Object A".  If a method of Object B calls A.respond_with, and then a method of Object C calls A.respond_with, then I would get an error.  But that's not correct - I only want an error if the instance method of Object B calls A.respond_with twice OR if the instance method of Object C calls A.respond_with twice.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way I could think of - in your Ruby class, define a @responded attribute by doing `attr_accessor :responded`. In your `respond_with` method, add the following lines:

```
def respond_with
  raise DoubleRenderError if self.responded
  # do stuff
  self.responded = true
end
```

The above code should raise an error if you call respond_with twice on the same object.